# Is it polite to accept an answer you have provided to a question you asked?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, answers

It feels a little perverse or impolite to accept an answer if you both *asked* and *answered* a question. Is there any protocol for such situations?

I feel as though the original questioner should be able to pass the buck to moderators or some independent group to accept answers when they have contributed one of the answers. Could this work or it it OK to accept?

Answer (score 6):

If your answer is the best one, accept it. It doesn't give you reputation, however.

Comment: Another thing to be aware of: your own answer is not brought at the top when accepted, it keeps its order based on votes.

Comment: Unanswered questions also clutter up the queue.

Comment: @Suma, OP was asking about **accepting** your own answer. Has nothing to do with votes.

Comment: @Eric Ordering has to do with votes. It has to do with accepting as well (accepted is placed on top, even in front of most voted), but not when you accept your own answer.

Comment: It would be considered polite to wait a few days before accepting. Otherwise it appears like you won't consider other answers that may turn out to be better.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's perfectly okay.

There's even a tick box for it when making a question.

[image: tick box for answering your own question when making a question]

Comment: The question is not about answering your own question: it's about **accepting** your own answer to your own question

Comment: Yes, I am aware.